# How do I freeze a chart in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have 2 columns of data and a chart on the right side.

I'd like to freeze the location of the chart so that I can scroll up and down to view the data while viewing the chart at the same time.

How do I do this in Excel 2007?

Comment: I've been a little busy w/ Thanksgiving. I'll accept it once I have a moment to check it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two way to do this:

- One is to open a second window to the same worksheet, so you see the data in one and the chart in the other - in Excel 2003 it is found in Window > New Window. It will be in a similar place in Excel 2007.

[image]

- The second method is to split the window into two panes, either top and bottom or left and right. These can be scrolled independently.

[image]

[image]